# AngularJS - Not able to access outside variables inside $http

Tags: angularjs, http, variables, error-handling, closures

I have a $http.get request

```
function a(event) {
var target = $(event.currentTarget);
$http.get(url).then(function() {
},
function() {
//Not able to access target.
});
}
```

Inside the error callback, the target variable is coming undefined. Why?

Comment: `$(event.currentTarget)` what is this? Show more code

Comment: console.log(target) before the call, is it undefined?

Answer (score 0):

It's not that you can't access the target variable, it's that $(event.currentTarget) is undefined.

Use:

```
var target = event.target;
```